# How can i remove a single space or tab in the hungry mode?

Tags: indentation, package

I use package [hungry-delete](https://github.com/nflath/hungry-delete) for deleting whole indentation but I don't know how can I force removing a single space or tab in that mode. Is there any way to do it or do I need to temporarily disable the hungry mode?

Comment: Select it and delete.